# access /bin in custom shell - C

Tags: c, shell, unix

I am trying to make my own shell in C.
I can access files from my current working dir using the below:

```
getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
```

When i type "cd file" i need my shell to access **/bin** first and not my cwd.

For example when i type "ls" it should try /bin/ls. If that fails then try /usr/bin/ls.

The shell shouldn't search the current working directory by default.

How can i do this? Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: You will have to have a list of search paths maintained in your code, and then you will try these one by one. Not sure what other suggestion could be here

Comment: It’s using PATH env, change it to be whatever you want.

Comment: I would add to that: if it's **not** using the `PATH` environment variable, make it that it **does** use that. And only if `PATH` does not exist, probably use some sane defaults.

Comment: For some inspiration, you can take a look at the command `strace sh -c ls`. You will see it performs a number of calls to `stat` to see where the `ls` command is located.